# How do I address the link folder that returns in the log?

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I'm trying to run a legacy project from the company's years and I'm stuck. This http link is in another project folder how do I address it? or how do i solve this? all the settings for the project to run are in a .properties file

```
`java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/InternalService
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1890)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1492)
    at neumann.utility.HTTPMessageSender.sendHTTPMessage(HTTPMessageSender.java:73)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.externalcommunications.ExtBalancerSender.getBalancerStatusSavedData(ExtBalancerSender.java:106)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.getGameServerData(GamesTrafficLight.java:220)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.updateEnabledGameList(GamesTrafficLight.java:201)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.init(GamesTrafficLight.java:122)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.<init>(GamesTrafficLight.java:88)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.getInstance(GamesTrafficLight.java:138)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.GamesMain.main(GamesMain.java:89)
Exception in thread "main" neumann.exception.AppException: [GameTrafficLight.getGameServerData] Unable to get Server data from balancer
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.getGameServerData(GamesTrafficLight.java:222)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.updateEnabledGameList(GamesTrafficLight.java:201)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.init(GamesTrafficLight.java:122)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.<init>(GamesTrafficLight.java:88)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.services.GamesTrafficLight.getInstance(GamesTrafficLight.java:138)
    at neumann.gameserver.games.GamesMain.main(GamesMain.java:89)
```

`

and here is the .properties file

```
app_name=[GS-WS] 

email_address0=system.c@egaming.net

smtp_address0=mail.egaming.net

#server_socket_host=10.10.30.12
server_socket_host=127.0.0.1

server_socket_port=40001:websocketconn

server_running_mode=live

server_logger_name=webapp;applogger;systemmonitor;flashlogger;admintool;1011;1012;1013;1019;1035;1038;1048;1049;1051;1054;1055;1057;1058;1059;2006;4001;4002;4003;5001;5002;5006;9005;9007

server_logger_path=/var/log/services/gs/casinows/

games_list_enabled_game = 1011:100~1012:100~1013:100~1019:100~1035:100~1038:100~1048:100~1049:100~1051:100~1054:100~1055:100~1057:100~1058:100~1059:100~2006:100~4001:100~4002:100~4003:100~5001:100~5002:100~5006:100~6001:100~9003:100~9005:100~9007


system_currency = 1

games_cashier_jurisdiction_level = nation

games_initial_cashier = 1

server_database_pool_name=BoneCP:pool:pool_slave


#cache_server_data=cache_server_data~192.168.0.1:60001~10~pool



#balancer_server_data=balancer_server_data~192.168.0.1:60002~10~pool

server_group_type = 1


admin_tool_trafficlight = false

internal_service_path =
login_server_data = http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/InternalService


internal_service_url = http://127.0.0.1:8080/services/InternalService



#cache_system = redis:127.0.0.1:8080
cache_system = memory



enable_ping_service =  true
```

`

what can i be doing to resolve this?